# how to implement dtmf

Tags: iphone, dtmf

hi any of them know how to implement dtmf in iphone application. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't just do a Google search? The first result for "iPhone DTMF" returns this Google Code project called [iPhreak](http://code.google.com/p/iphreak/) which should include what you're looking for.

Comment: yes, i got that, but it is runnable state, help me

Answer (score 1):

Generating [DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency) is easy - you just need to generate two sinusoids at the appropriate frequencies.

Decoding [DTMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency) is a little harder, but it can be implemented using a pair of [Goertzel filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm).